# How to protect an application against virtual machine time tracking loss issue?

Tags: java, time, virtual-machine, virtualization, drift

#### SCENARIO

We have an app written in Java. It used to run on a physical machine smoothly.
The decision to move to virtual machine has been taken. Now, the app presents regularly inaccuraccies in the timestamps of the logs.

#### ILLUSTRATION

*BEFORE virtualization*

```
Timestamp    | Caller | Message
00:00:01.735 |  foo   | Downloading something
00:00:05.123 |  foo   | Downloaded something
00:00:05.123 |  bar   | Analyzing something
...
00:00:08.990 |  foo   | END
```

As you can see, the timestamp values grow continously on the physical machine.

*AFTER virtualization*

```
Timestamp    | Caller | Message
00:00:01.735 |  foo   | Downloading something
00:00:05.123 |  bar   | Downloaded something
00:00:05.123 |  baz   | Analyzing something
...
00:00:04.485 |  foo   | END
```

Now, the logs state that the process ends during the download.

#### SOLUTIONS TAKEN

We have synchronized the VM with NTP servers. The issue disappeared for some days. It is back now.

#### QUESTIONS

- Should we synchronized more often?
- Can we imagine to override somehow `System.currentTimeMillis()`?
- Should we change the timestamps values in the log based on detected time drift?
- How to solve the virtual machine time tracking loss issue?

**Host OS:** RHEL 6.5
**Guest OS:** RHEL 5.4
**Virtualization Platform:** RHEV 3.4

Comment: It is not clear how time drift can directly cause the incorrect timestamps you report. It is possible that running on a VM + time drift triggers a problem in your app (a race condition perhaps) which manifests as the logs problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose between different options

- Have a precise time with more frequent time sync, but more inconsistencies in timestamp ordering ...
- Have a less precise time by making less frequent time sync, or even totally disable it, but more consistent in timestamp ordering ...

From what I know, it's not possible to have the same accuracy as in a hardware computer.

Comment: What about correcting the timestamp values based on the detected time drifting?

Comment: building a computation on a somewhat random measure will never bring something you can rely on. At some time, VM clock will be too fast, and other time too slow ... If you really need a reliable ordering of your events, you have to find something else than the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

`currentTimeMillis()` is thread-safe out of the box, but because it's based on the OS's clock time, it can suffer inaccuracies if the system's clock-time is changed, and is prone to *time-drift* (cumulative increase in inaccuracy).

`nanoTime()` is *not* thread-safe out of the box, but uses the system's "atomic clock" instead (***when possible****), being *immune* to changes to the system's clock, being *appropriate* if your objective is just printing time-stamps on or of events independent from it, and a lot *less prone* to time-drift when used in loops for operations that ***are dependent**** from it, although over very long periods, time-drift can become noticeable.

- ***** - Some specific OSs don't offer or support "atomic clocks" at all, and in these specific cases, Java ***has no choice*** but to use the normal clock. Please google about it if you suspect your system might be one of these.
- ***** - What I mean by *"dependent"* operations here is when methods or actions are triggered by, or have values that are dependent upon, elapsed time since a last call of the same or different method, like in a *game loop*.

  - It happens because the time stamp is just that, a time stamp, and it doesn't take into account the time the operation itself takes to be executed.

---

This doesn't seem to be your case, but if you ever face a situation where you're implementing operations that are *dependent* on the time stamps as explained in the last note of the section above, what you want to do is implement a ***delta-time***, which uses the `nanoTime()` time stamps to get accurate bearing on elapsed time between measurements, but that also allows for a delta to be used.

Delta-time is the correct method to do ***animations*** for example.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it was a bug from RHEL 5.4. Upgrading the Guest OS to RHEL 5.11 solves the issue.

Comment: Unfortunate none of our explanations on actual code implementations were related to the resolving of the issue, but none the less glad to hear that you've managed to fix it mate. =)